# Performance/Optimized way to perform PostgreSQL query. WHERE OR vs WHERE IN?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a simple query that selects all records in a table that match the id criteria provided.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = x or id = y or id = z;
```

It works fine, however I have over 50 ID's that need to be included in the where clause. So when it comes to performance, would it be better to do a WHERE IN clause, rather than OR? Or is there a better way to execute this that I am totally overlooking?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried profiling them both to see which is better?

Comment: The `IN` will compile to a string of `OR` statements.  They are no different.  You can try inserting all of the values into a temp table and doing either a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS` clause over it.

Comment: @Siyual I think an `IN` actually gets converted to an `id = any(array)`, at least that happens with `CHECK` constraints involving `IN`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostrgeSQL behavior can be checked with `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)`.
This is the only way to understand what database is doing.

In case your list grows big, you can try joining with a `VALUES` construct instead.
Please, check these:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in
- https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/